# How to show a message before 'Usage data access' opens for user to grant permission in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, usage-statistics

I am using the package "app_usage" to get user data in my app. It however directly opens the usage page without any context. This is as written in the package
[as can be seen in the photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtAiq.png)

Now how do I go about showing a screen where I ask the user to grant this permission? it is a protected permission so the user needs to explicitly consent but I would like the user to see something on my app before being taken to settings. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can display a dialog box that alerts the user:

```
void _showConfirmation() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
              title: new Text("App usage"),
              content: new Text("We're getting information about your app usage. If you didn't grant the permission yet, you'll be redirected to the settings page"),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Ok'),
                  onPressed: () {
                     _showConfirmation();
                     Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            ));
  }
  void getUsageStats() async {
    try {
      DateTime startDate = DateTime(2018, 01, 01);
      DateTime endDate = new DateTime.now();
      List<AppUsageInfo> infos = await AppUsage.getAppUsage(startDate, endDate);
      setState(() {
        _infos = infos;
      });
    } on AppUsageException catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
    }
  }
```

You can execute the `_showConfirmation()` function immediately after the layout has been loaded:

```
@override
void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _showConfirmation());
}
```

Comment: Hi!
How do I call _showConfirmation()? Putting it in initState gives the error:
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_LocalizationsScope>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _MyRiveAnimationState.initState() completed.

Comment: Code has been edited to allow _showConfirmation() to be called immediately after the layout has been loaded